# Pivot Table VBA Error from Recorded Macro

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Below is my update to the code. TableX is the referenced table that my pivot tables will use. After declaring the 'shtReport' variable as a Worksheet and further naming the variable, the error 'Object variable or With block variable not set' occurs.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub SutoPivot()

    Dim PvtTbl                          As PivotTable
    Dim PvtCache                        As PivotCache
    Dim shtReport                       As Worksheet

    ' set the Pivot Cache  (NOT SURE what is "TableX" ?)
    Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="TableX", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
    Set shtReport = Worksheets("Invoice Data")

    ' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Invoice Data").PivotTables("PivotTable1a")

    On Error GoTo 0
    If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then
        ' create a new Pivot Table in "Invoice Data" sheet, start from Cell Y1
        Set PvtTbl = shtReport.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=Worksheets("Invoice Data").Range("Y1"), _ TableName:="PivotTable1a")

        With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Sales Director")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Manager")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With

        With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Owner")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 3
        End With

        With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Account Name")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 4
        End With

        With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Business Name")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 5
        End With

        With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Annual Aggregate Volume")
            .Orientation = xlValuesField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        PvtTbl.AddDataField PvtTbl.PivotFields("Annual Aggregate Volume"),
            "Sum of Annual Aggregate Volume", xlSum

        With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Sum of Annual Aggregate Volume")
            .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        End With

    Else
        ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
        PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
        PvtTbl.RefreshTable
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Where's the start of the macro?

Comment: Hi BruceWayne, the error starts in the first section of code, which is also where the macro begins. I recorded this macro and attempted to implement the record in my data. It gives me that error.

Comment: @J.Woe have you tested the code in my answer below ? is it working for you like you intended ?

Comment: Hi Shai Rado, I really appreciate the follow up. I implemented your code, but it gave an error of 'Variable not defined' while highlighting 'shtReport.'. I tried fixing it and came up with this line of code, edited in the original post for your oversight. It now gives me an 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error. Thanks again, your thoroughness is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will get you started on automating the creation and updating of `PivotTables` in VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SutoPivot()

Dim PvtTbl                          As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache                        As PivotCache

' set the Pivot Cache  (NOT SURE what is "TableX" ?)
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="TableX", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Invoice Data").PivotTables("PivotTable1a")

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then
    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Invoice Data" sheet, start from Cell Y1
    Set PvtTbl = shtReport.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=Worksheets("Invoice Data").Range("Y1"), TableName:="PivotTable1a")

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Director")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Manager")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Owner")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Account Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 4
    End With

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Business Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 5
    End With

    PvtTbl.AddDataField PvtTbl.PivotFields("Annual Aggregate Volume"), _
        "Sum of Annual Aggregate Volume", xlSum

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Sum of Annual Aggregate Volume")
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End With

Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range  
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```