# Application-defined or object-defined error when running PivotCache.Refresh in macro

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have 8 pivot tables I am attempting to refresh the pivot cache for using a macro (same Source). Each pivot table is named PivotTableWPI1, PivotTableWPI2, ... , PivotTableWPI8. So I wrote a For loop to do this.

I am getting **Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error**

```
Private Sub resetPivotCache()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim pSheet As Worksheet
Set pSheet = wb.Sheets("Pivot")
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 8
        pSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableWPI" & i).PivotCache.Refresh
    Next i

End Sub
```

I have actually tried the following form too:

```
Private Sub resetPivotCache()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim pSheet As Worksheet
Set pSheet = wb.Sheets("Pivot")
Dim i As Integer

    With pSheet    
        For i = 1 To 8
            PivotTables("PivotTableWPI" & i).PivotCache.Refresh
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Still throws the same error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've answered a similar post (without the `For` loop) here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862748/pivot-table-vba-error-from-recorded-macro/41867900#41867900

Comment: are all PivotTable's Cache set to the same data source ? can you specify it's location ?

Comment: I figured out that since all the pivot tables are set to the same source, this code was overkill. Overall problem solved.