# VBA excel modifying fields in an existing pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba excel and I am opening an existing workbook and sheet with a pivot table in it and I need to add a field to the pivot table so that I can access data on the sheet that is not currently there. When I give focus to the pivot table on the right hand side a PivotTable Fields box pops up with a lists of different fields it can show. I need to add one of those fields because it is not currently checked.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837987.aspx

Comment: see how to handle `PivotTable` with VBA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862748/pivot-table-vba-error-from-recorded-macro/41867900#41867900